# Compile R source code in a nfs (network file system) disk format partition

Tags: r, installation, compiler-warnings

when compiling R 3.1.0 to install in a partition (NFS format) of a server, I encounter an error as follow.

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/download/R-3.1.0/src/library/base'
mv: preserving permissions for `all.R': Operation not supported
make[4]: *** [mkRbase] Error 1
```

Someone suggest it should be related with NFS format. But how to tackle it?

Comment: Why is a R 3.1.0 using a path with "3.0.0" in it? And also is "downlooad" a typo? Is this really the error message?

Comment: @Spacedman, Thank you. Both 3.1.0 and 3.0.0 have this problem. downlooad is just a name (yeh, indeed a typo when mkdir)

Comment: R is fairly transportable - compile it on a local drive then copy the tree to the NFS folder. You may have to change the definition of R_HOME set somewhere, but I thought the latest R script worked out where it was itself...

Comment: @Spacedman I configured R with `./configure --prefix=/home/XXX/local/R --enable-R-shlib` in my local machine. After transfering the whole R dir, I found it didnot work due to the lib problem. such as, `error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` This seems  the result of different lib in the local and server.